# Looking for some examples of functions with a property.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I am looking for some examples of functions $f$ satisfy $$\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}-f(\frac{a+b}{2})=g(a-b),$$ where $a,b$ are two distinct points on the domain of $f$, and  $g$ can be any functions.

**My attempt:** I tested $f(t)=t^2$ and  got $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-(\frac{a+b}{2})^2=\frac{(a-b)^{2}}4=g(a-b).$$ In this case, we can let $g(t)=\frac{t^2}{4}$. Are there any other examples of the $f$, $g$  satisfy the above equation ?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: $ f(x)=\alpha +\beta x+\gamma x^{2}$ has this property.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f$ and $g$ are zero functions, means, $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x$ in domain $f$ and $g$